# modify javascript header response

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, http-headers

I have the following script in javascript.

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    //Get contents of response
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;
//Set new headers 
 headers['X-Robots-Tag'] = [{key: 'X-Robots-Tag', value: 'noindex'}]; 

    callback(null, response);
};
```

Every request he returns he modifies the X-Robots-Tag for the value of noindex.

Now another demand has arisen in which I have to pass another header just for a specific uri.

Example, I would like to,  When you arrive, a request for:

**[www.mydomain.com/ads](http://www.mydomain.com/ads)**

insert in the headers

```
X-Ads-Tag value: true : Exemple headers['X-Ads-Tag'] = [{key: 'X-Ads-Tag', value: 'true'}];
```

and when a request comes in

**[www.mydomain.com/marketing](http://www.mydomain.com/marketing)**

insert in the headers

```
Value X-Marketing-Tag: true : Exemple headers['X-Marketing-Tag'] = [{key: 'X-Marketing-Tag', value: 'true'}];
```

a url will always be the same, which can change and in the future have more different uri and new headings for each one.

```
Example uri:
/ads
/marketing
/hub
/gamming
```

placing these constants he brings me the uri that arrives.

```
const uri = response.uri;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? *Can someone help me?* Help you with what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you are able to get the `uri` for the current request you can simply do

```js
const uri = response.uri;
if (/^\/ads/i.test(uri)) {
  headers['X-Ad-Tag'] = [{key: 'X-Ad-Tag', value: 'true'}]; 
} else if (/^\/marketing/i.test(uri)) {
  headers['X-Marketing-Tag'] = [{key: 'X-Marketing-Tag', value: 'true'}]; 
}
```

`/^\/ads/i.test(uri)` is a regular expression, which tests whether the uri starts with `/ads`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function which will check url and based on url it will add more headers.

```
export.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  //Get contents of response
  const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
  const headers = response.headers;
  addMoreHeaders(response.uri, headers)
  //Set new headers 
  headers['X-Robots-Tag'] = [{
    key: 'X-Robots-Tag',
    value: 'noindex'
  }];


  callback(null, response);
};

const addMoreHeaders = (url, headers) {
  let key = ""
  let value = ""
  const name = ""
  const urls = url.split('/')
  const end = urls[urls.length - 1]
  switch (end) {
    case 'ads':
      key = "ab";
      value = "v";
      name = "ads";
      break;
      .....
  }
  headers[name] = [{
    key,
    value
  }]
}
```